# Routing with parameters not working on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I've been trying to figure this one out but I'm becoming desperate because I don't see why this isn't working.
Whatever I try, no route is matching my link and I get the following error:

> Routing Error: uninitialized constant LineItemsController

My link looks like this:

```
<%= button_to 'Add to template', line_items_path(template_id: @template, position_id: position) %>
```

So the link being created is:

> http://localhost:3000/line_items?position_id=2&template_id=1

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resources :line_items
    resources :templates
    resources :positions
```

line_item_controller.rb

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /line_items
  # GET /line_items.json
  def index
    @line_items = LineItem.all
  end

  # GET /line_items/1
  # GET /line_items/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /line_items/new
  def new
    @line_item = LineItem.new
  end

  # GET /line_items/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /line_items
  # POST /line_items.json
  def create
    position = Position.find(params[:position_id])
    template = Template.find(params[:template_id])
    @line_item = LineItem.new(position, template)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to template_url}
        format.js {@current_item = @line_item}
        format.json { render action: 'show',
          status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors,
          status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /line_items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /line_items/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.update(line_item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item, notice: 'Line item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /line_items/1
  # DELETE /line_items/1.json
  def destroy
    @line_item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to line_items_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_line_item
      @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
#    def line_item_params
#      params.require(:line_item).permit(:position_id, :template_id)
#    end
  #...
end
```

From my understanding, my link should send a POST request that should call the `create` action of the `line_item controller`, thereby matching the route `POST  /line_items(.:format) line_items#create`

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is the filename of your controller:

`line_item_controller.rb` should be `line_items_controller.rb`

Comment: Oh jeeez, that actually works. I've been trying around for hours now and wasn't able to figure it out? I guess that happens when you're still getting used to the whole "convention over configuration" thing. Huge thanks for the simple solution :).

Comment: My pleasure sir :)